# scrollIntoView not working when triggered via onClick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a button which when clicked should scroll the page down to meet a div. I created a scrollIntoView function in JavaScript and linked it to the button (a tag) with an onClick. The onClick is working because it triggers the console.log, but it doesn't trigger the scroll event.
Here is the code, HTML and JavaScript.
HTML

```
<div class="arrowContainer">
      <a type="button" onClick="move();" id="arrowBtn" data-scroll href="#">
            <div class="arrow"></div>
      </a>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function move() {
    document.querySelector('.experience').scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
    console.log('Is it working?')
};
```

So since I noticed the onClick was not triggering the scrolling, I added move() underneath the function, and as the page was reloaded the scroll function + console.log worked properly. I have no idea what I have done to stop it from working properly.
Any help would be really appreciated. Also its probably something really obvious as I'm new to JavaScript.

Comment: You’re not preventing the default behavior of the link, which has a href of `#`, which will cause it to scroll to the top of the page. Use `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @Terry Thanks for your comment. Where should i add the event.preventDefault()? just put it near the console.log? Thanks so much again.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, use of `href="#exampleid"` should do the trick and teleport to element with `id="exampleid"`, so you could use id instead of class.

Here is your code based on class

```js
function move(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   document.querySelector('.experience').scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
   });
};
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" onClick="move(event);" id="arrowBtn">
      <div class="arrow">arrow</div>
    </a>
      <div style="height:1000px;"></div>
      <div class="experience">experience</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is simplest and without js:

```css
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <a href="#experience" id="arrowBtn">
      <div class="arrow">arrow</div>
    </a>
    <div style="height:1000px;"></div>
    <div id="experience">experience</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### One more...

Your anchor tag (`<a></a>`) have `type` attribute, but it's not like `<input>` type. It stands for

> media type of the linked document [a type](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_type.asp)

and you could use it like this:

```html
<a href="example.com/img.png" type="image/png">image link</a>
```